# How to use a function from another file in Main App function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React.js, i think that question is simple but i can't find a simple solution. I'm trying to use functions instead of classes and i don't know how to use these functions in Main function as a component. Let me explain better:

- I have a main function called "App.js".
- I have another function that i want to use as a component inside of "App.js" called "Menu(file)/index.js;"

Follow the code:

APP.JS

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { DivPrincipal} from "./styles";
    import {Menu} from "../../components/Menu/index"
    import {DivContent} from "../../components/Content-Kanban/styles"

    function App() {
      return (
        <DivPrincipal>
          <Menu>

          </Menu>
          <DivContent>

          </DivContent>
        </DivPrincipal>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

AND THE MENU FUNCTION:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { DivMenu } from './styles';

    function Menu() {
      return <DivMenu>
          
      </DivMenu>;
    }

    export default Menu;
```

When I import the Menu function to Main App function, I'm getting this error:

> ./src/pages/Main/App.js
> Attempted import error: 'Menu' is not exported from '../../components/Menu/index'.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting your component as `export default Menu`.

Based on that you should try importing instead of `{ Menu }` as only `Menu`:

```
import Menu from "../../components/Menu/index"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the difference between `export` and `export default`.

If you `export default X`, you import it as `import X from './path'`. If you `export X`, you import it as `import { X } from './path'`.

Comment: Very good, doesn't knew that!